# (too) frequent MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm facing a dilemma regarding how to store data a user generates, because they do so very frequently.

You see, the general idea of the program is that the user answers MPC-questions, and that their progress gets stored and shown - i.e., the more questions are answered correctly, the closer to a 100% the user gets, which is updated in the DB with every answer, as well as on screen. Note that the longer a user is doing this, the faster their answers become, up to the point of answering every 1,5 second. This will NOT be uncommon.

You can see how this adds to the number of queries made - and that's without taking additional users into consideration.

Now I've thought of regular-interval updates (every X questions, or every Y minutes, etc.), but that comes with the risk of the client closing the session and effectively destroying data I would very much love to have had. I've also thought of cookies, which hold data that's read at every login, but this will always entail that the user's last session will not be stored. Also: the restriction on cookie size and numbers make this worthless, as my program offers TONS of different topics of which MPC-Questions are created.

**So the question is: how can I be as efficient as possible in the amount of queries made, without losing data?** Is there a common approach to this type of problem - I mean, how do statistical or just DB-heavy websites pull this stuff off?!

(Also: 80% of the program is JS (Jquery). Just sayin'.)

I'm curious what solutions or ideas will come up!

Comment: I really do not thing MySQL will be the bottleneck here. Seams like all the polling requests with the server will be way slower than your MySQL requests, unless you structure your SQL calls really poorly. If this actually becomes a problem I would scale up (e.x. MySQL cluster) instead of optimizing here, because as long as you want to retain all the data and also still want to use MySQL you are kind of stuck with the approach of storing everything imediatly. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: You can safely load a users history on login and keep it in a server-sided cache, no need to query that again if you know it to be immutable. Updates of scores can be directly be stored in cache, and asynchronous jobs on the server store it in the database to avoid a long wait time on peak moments, and finally, if you're updating records of different users in a single table, go for `InnoDB` (or `XtraDB`), but _not_ `MyISAM`. Then you just need the hardware to match your needs, possibly in a cluster if it scales beyond a decent servers capabilities.

Comment: If however, you don't really need the data, of aren't particularly bothered by users 'cheating', a [browser sided storage](http://google-opensource.blogspot.nl/2009/05/web-storage-portability-layer-common.html) (possibly synced once in a while) also lowers the load considerably.

Comment: Wrikken, could you be so kind as to help me with this, in more detail? I see that you're Dutch like I am, so I'd very much like to personally correspond with you via e-mail, or even Skype. If you'd like that too, that is.

I have the feeling this isn't as hard as it sounds (I already found some plugins that specifically help to locally store large chunks of data), but It's not the ease of use, but the reliability I'm worried about - precisely because I'm not familiar with it.